# Long Tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex, miktex

I am inserting a table in to a file that already has some text in it. This is at the end of a section and right before the beginning of another.

First I added the following code (sample, the real table is a real long one)

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c}
    a&b&c&d\\
    \hline
    c&d&e&f\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Everything is fine. However I realise I need a caption to the table. So, then I changed the code to:

```
\begin{table}
    \caption {title}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c}
        a&b&c&d\\
        \hline
        c&d&e&f\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Now the table jumps into the next section and starts 3-4 lines after the next section.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `longtable` package. or you can use `\begin{table}[!h]`